# Form outside of wordpress gives wordpress 404 on submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site, and a subdirectory on that server which has been excluded from wordpress. This is the line I'm using in the .htaccess file to exclude that directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(app) [NC]
```

I have a form inside that directory. Whenever one of the fields contains a URL, I get a wordpress 404 on submit. If the field does not contain a URL, it submits normally. How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

Here's what I've tried:

- Adding a prefix to the name of the form element
- Using a random string of characters as the form element name
- Encoding the value to base64 on form submission
- Adding an .htaccess file to the subdirectory with a RewriteEngine Off command
- Adding an "action" attribute to the form, both to itself and to another page, with relative and full URLs.

Here's the full text of the wordpress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(app) [NC]
RewriteRule ^other/(.*) /wp-includes/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ext/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/main\.css //index.php?style_wrapper=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/(.*) /wp-content/themes/sirens/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/sirens/screenshot\.png|readme\.html|license\.txt|wp-content/debug\.log|wp-includes/$ /nothing_404_404 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

Here's the form:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
   <textarea id = "orders" name = "orders"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Place order" class=" btn btn-blue">
</form>
```

In every case, the result is the same - it works without a URL in the field, but goes to a wordpress 404 page when there is a URL in the field.

Example:

- Textarea contains "foo". The form submits without issue.
- Textarea contains "http://foo.com". The form goes to a 404.

Comment: what is the name attribute for website field, it happens in wordpress when we use some reserved keyword in attributes name, try to change that.....

Comment: The field name is "orders", but I thought excluding the directory excluded all traffic to that directory.

Comment: try to replace orders to anything....and give a try

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. In fact, even encoding it to base64 first doesn't work.

Comment: Is this the wordpress .htaccess file? or another one? Is it possible your Wordpress rewrite rules are overriding your rule above?

Comment: It's in the wordpress .htaccess file, in the site's root directory.

Comment: What happens when you submit an empty form? Do you use fields named "hour", "minute" and/or "date"? It's reserved too, not just the "orders".

Comment: Like I said in the question, only submitting a URL causes the 404.

Comment: Could you show the example form?

Comment: Did you try to set an "action" on your form like this :
`action="#_"` ?

Comment: Add the action attribute. Try both relative and absolute (with and without the http). Be sure you are hitting the target / posting to the right area (change action to http://example.com and you should be taken off page). If action="" (left blank) the form will submit to self (var_dump() that!). No JS in the way right? drop a ```var_dump(post);``` on the target page see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand this: `Whenever one of the fields contains a URL`. What do you exactly mean by that ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: For example, if I enter "foo" into the textarea, it submits no problem. If I enter http://foo.com, it goes to a 404. EDIT: I can't enter a fully qualified URL into this comment box, I'll edit my original post to clarify.

Comment: What does the form's handler do with the information submitted? Could it be a problem with the handler itself?

Comment: I tried to produced your issue with fresh WordPress installation and it is working normally. i can submit it just fine. i think the issue here is not the htaccess. can you try to add action url into your form?

Comment: It sounds like there is some sort of redirection happening that is either blocked or invalid. Are you redirecting on form submission?

Comment: All it's doing is inserting lines into the database. IE, it calls explode("\n", $_POST['orders']), cleans each line, then inserts it into the database. The purpose of this is just to store referral links. There is no redirection afterward - the form posts to itself only.

Answer (score 0):

Which .htaccess file are you adding your rule to? The default Wordpress .htaccess, or within your subdirectory?

Perhaps creating an .htaccess file within your subdirectory with the following will help:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code ...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory-name/
....
```

Other will be same

It may help you..

Regards,
Nimesh P.